# Does maximum length of CN in a x509 cert include the length of the OIDs?

Tags: pki

This is a CN from a x509 certificate (I have done some substitutions just to mask the data but the length is not changed)

CN=Alex Perry/pseudonym=88b2e76beE0e4e4b94b502020202262E/x500UniqueIdentifier=22e4EE844E8B744490EEE96EE8BEB7E29548e4496E425247944B025E04528654/postalCode=60601

As per the RFC, the CN field should not be more than 64 bytes, but this CN is more than 64 bytes

So does the max length 64 only counted up for the CN=Alex Perry & the rest of the string (/pseudonym, /x500UniqueIdentifier etc) is ignored?

If so, is there a limit imposed on the total maximum length? What is that?

Comment: It looks to me that you've posted a distinguished name (DN) with several attributes where the CN is just one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are separate fields. Their lengths, from the very same RFC:

`ub-pseudonym INTEGER ::= 128`

`ub-postal-code-length INTEGER ::= 16`

If `x500UniqueIdentifier` is OID 2.5.4.45 then it is a bit-string which isn't constrained in length (afaik).

Both the `Subject` and the `Issuer` fields are instances of `RelativeDistinguishedName` (section 4.1.2.4) and are of `SIZE (1..MAX)`

Appendix B says that:

> MAX indicates that the upper bound is unspecified.    Implementations
>   are free to choose an upper bound that suits their    environment.

So while the definition suggests that `Subject` can be as large as you want it to be, it also suggests that it may well be constrained by your particular implementation.

Comment: Is there any upper limit for the who Subject field combined?

Comment: Issuer and Subject are not instances of `RelativeDistinguishedName`, but of `RDNSequence` which holds a sequence of `RelativeDistinguishedName`s and the `SIZE (1..MAX)` applies to the number of attributes that every `RelativeDistinguishedName` can hold and, AFAIK, RFC 5280 doesn't say anything about size constraints for the `RDNSequence` itself.